# How to create squareGrid on leaflet map with turf.js grid and OSM data

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson, turf

I am a beginner in using leaflet map and turf.js and want to show square grid of the OSM data which I will fetch from OSM db. I saw multiple example of turf.js but did not find any perfect example as per my requirement.

I found below image on internet which is showing what I want (I only want squares on map not these custom images). So please suggest me a way/code to achieve this feature.

[image]

I am using below code to create grid but it is creating a particular block of grid on map but I want to do with OSM coordinates and want to have it all over map.

```
var bbox = [121.51083, 25.05127, 121.5441, 25.06838];
var data = turf.bboxPolygon(bbox);
var center = turf.center(data);
var squareGrid = turf.squareGrid(bbox, 0.25, 'kilometers');
            
var gridLayer = L.geoJSON(squareGrid, {color: "#000000", weight: 1, fill:"#cccccc"}).addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(gridLayer.getBounds());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "OSM coordinates"?

Comment: Do you need something like this: https://unpkg.com/leaflet-auto-graticule@1.1.1/example.html?

Comment: @TomazicM I want to show something similar to https://app.nextearth.io/ site.