# How to make selection of multiple grids via mouse click and hover event on leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I am working on a project where I need to create a map and show grid on map just like the website https://app.nextearth.io/. I was able to create grid using below code but don't know how to create mouse events so that I can click on a grid box and then other grids on which user hover mouse will get selected.

Code which I used to create grids (I am using leaflet map)

```
var qtrArray = [];
    var linesArray = [];
    var Startlatlng;
    var llOffset = 0.0666666666666667;

    var drawGridBox = false;
    var gridline;
    var polylinesquare;
    var latPolylines = [];
    var lngPolylines = [];
    var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds();

    var map = L.map("map").setView([31.771959, 35.217018], 10);


    map.on('click', function(event) {
        createGridBox(event.latlng);
        
    });

    DrawGridOn();

    map.on('moveend', function(event) {        
        createGridLines(map.getBounds());
    });
    

    function DrawGridOn() {
        drawGridBox = true;
    }

    function DrawGridOff() {
        drawGridBox = false;
    }


    function ClearLastGrid() {
        map.removeLayer(polyline);
    }

    function createGridLines(bounds) {
        //console.log("North -"+bounds.getNorthEast().wrap().lat);
        
        for (var i=0; i< latPolylines.length; i++) {
                //latPolylines[i].setMap(null);
                map.removeLayer(latPolylines[i]);
        }
        latPolylines = [];
        for (var i=0; i< lngPolylines.length; i++) {
                //lngPolylines[i].setMap(null);
                map.removeLayer(lngPolylines[i]);
        }
        lngPolylines = [];
        if (map.getZoom() <= 6) return; 
        
        var north = bounds.getNorthEast().wrap().lat;
        var east = bounds.getNorthEast().wrap().lng;
        var south = bounds.getSouthWest().wrap().lat;
        var west = bounds.getSouthWest().wrap().lng;
        
        

        // define the size of the grid
        var topLat = Math.ceil(north / llOffset) * llOffset;
        var rightLong = Math.ceil(east / llOffset) * llOffset;

        var bottomLat = Math.floor(south / llOffset) * llOffset;
        var leftLong = Math.floor(west / llOffset) * llOffset;

        for (var latitude = bottomLat; latitude <= topLat; latitude += llOffset) {
            // lines of latitude
            var pointA = new L.LatLng(latitude, leftLong);
            var pointB = new L.LatLng(latitude, rightLong);
            var pointList = [pointA, pointB];
            
            latPolyLayer = new L.rectangle(pointList, {
                color: '#9fd1d4',
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 0.5,
                smoothFactor: 1
            })
            
            latPolyLayer.addTo(map);
            latPolylines.push(latPolyLayer);
        }
        for (var longitude = leftLong; longitude <= rightLong; longitude += llOffset) {
            
            var pointA = new L.LatLng(topLat, longitude);
            var pointB = new L.LatLng(bottomLat, longitude);
            var pointList = [pointA, pointB];
            
            // lines of longitude
            lngPolyLayer = new L.rectangle(pointList, {
                color: '#9fd1d4',
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 0.5,
                smoothFactor: 1
            })
            
            lngPolyLayer.addTo(map);
            lngPolylines.push(lngPolyLayer);
        }
    }

    function createGridBox(point) {
        // Square limits
        var bottomLeftLat = Math.floor(point.lat / llOffset) * llOffset;
        var bottomLeftLong = Math.floor(point.lng / llOffset) * llOffset;

        var i;

        var gridLineSquare = [
        new L.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong), //lwr left
        new L.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong + llOffset), //lwr right
        new L.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + llOffset, bottomLeftLong + llOffset), //upr right
        new L.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + llOffset, bottomLeftLong),
        new L.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong)];


        for (i = 0; i < gridLineSquare.length; i++) {
            bounds.extend(gridLineSquare[i]);
        }

        // external.getData(event.latLng);
        if (drawGridBox == true) {
            polyline = new L.rectangle(gridLineSquare, {
                color: '#5f87b0',
                weight: 3,
                opacity: 0.5,
                smoothFactor: 1,
            }).on('click', function (e) {
                // There event is event object
                // there e.type === 'click'
                // there e.lanlng === L.LatLng on map
                // there e.target.getLatLngs() - your rectangle coordinates
                // but e.target !== rect
                //console.info(e.target.getLatLngs());
            });

            polyline.addTo(map);
            qtrArray.push(polyline);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could post code from this question as an answer to your own question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448441/how-to-create-squaregrid-on-leaflet-map-with-turf-js-grid-and-osm-data. It might help somebody with the same/similar question.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you mean by "create mouse events so that I can click on a grid box and then other grids on which user hover mouse will get selected". Please edit you question and explain that more in detail.

Comment: I think it means once a gird box is initially selected all other layers will be added to that selection when the user hovers over them? kind of confusing

Comment: You can add the grid to a `L.layerGroup()` and any other selected layers auto add to that layer group. Then have a button somewhere to clear that layer group to make a new selection...

Comment: @TomazicM Please have a look on https://app.nextearth.io/ site and you will understand what I want to implement.

Comment: Q/A on GIS SE site are not intended only to solve problem of particular user, but be helpful resource for anybody with similar questions/problems. That's the reason question has to be complete in itself, since outside links tend to get lost in time and also that there is no need to visit other sites to get complete picture of what the problem/question is. Please edit your question and add missing description of desired behavior.